# Knitr asis not working with output from hooks

Tags: r, templates, latex, knitr, rnw

In Rnw/LaTeX one use  of the common output from knitr hooks might be decorating  with some fancy environment the data from chunks.
For example code specific to chunk can produce core data for tables  and the hook code before and after provide the repetitive decorations.

Consider the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<myhooks,  include=FALSE>>=
printhook=function(before, options, envir) {
    if (before) {

        return('\nCommon R \\LaTeX\\ in before-hook')
    } else {
        return('\nCommon R \\LaTeX\\ in after-hook')
    }
}

knit_hooks$set(lprint = printhook)

@ 


<<test, results='asis', lprint=TRUE,  echo=FALSE>>=
cat("R \\LaTeX\\ in current chunk\n")
@ 

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the LaTeX output is approx like follows:

```
   \begin{kframe}
   Common R \LaTeX\ in before-hook
   \end{kframe}

   R \LaTeX\ in current chunk

   \begin{kframe}
   Common R \LaTeX\ in after-hook
   \end{kframe}
```

The hook code is not actually *asis*, but it gets wrapped in the `kframe` environment, which prevents from gluing the three pieces together.

How can we remove the enclosing `kframe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have an elegant solution for this problem. Below is one possible solution. The basic idea is to replace the output hook `chunk` when `results == 'asis'`, no source code is echoed, and no plots are produced in a code chunk:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<myhooks, include=FALSE>>=
local({
  hook_chunk = knit_hooks$get('chunk')
  knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
    x = hook_chunk(x, options)
    if (options$results == 'asis' && !options$echo && options$fig.num == 0) {
      # remove all kframe's
      gsub('\\\\(begin|end)\\{kframe\\}', '', x)
    } else x
  })
})
printhook=function(before, options, envir) {
    if (before) {
        return('\nCommon R \\LaTeX\\ in before-hook')
    } else {
        return('\nCommon R \\LaTeX\\ in after-hook')
    }
}
knit_hooks$set(lprint = printhook)
@

<<test, results='asis', lprint=TRUE,  echo=FALSE>>=
cat("R \\LaTeX\\ in current chunk\n")
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, it solved the problem. I realised that this is a shared need: [yihui.name/knitr/hooks#comment-1339608701](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks#comment-1339608701). Hopefully the possibility of circumventing kframes straight from single chunk hooks will be a feature in upcoming versions of knitr.